# how can I find out the sum of a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

I am really new to mongoDB. In the given data structure how can i sum the misscallcount field

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("596c5f6905c36efd35000009"), 
  "misscallDetails" : [
    {
        "contactId" : "1573778945692669180", 
        "misscallCount" : NumberInt(1), 
        "promotedOn" : ISODate("2017-08-04T13:54:17.298+0000")
    }, 
    {
        "contactId" : "1573778945692669180", 
        "misscallCount" : NumberInt(1), 
        "promotedOn" : ISODate("2017-08-04T13:56:17.243+0000")
    }
], 
"promoId" : ObjectId("596c5f4705c36efd35000003"),   
}
```

---

From comments:

I tried from my side but its give **total 0** ;

```
db.promoledger.aggregate( [ 
       { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$misscallDetails.misscallCount" } }}
 ])
```

Comment: what should be the resultant object?

Comment: Maybe you should look at some documentation and try something first. [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) would seem a logical place to start.

Comment: I tried from my side but its give total 0 ;
'db.promoledger.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: null, total: {  $sum:   "$misscallDetails.misscallCount"  }  }}])'

Comment: @Amit you must share what you've tried for others to guide what you can improve on.

Comment: @nullpointer  {  "total" : 2 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array before grouping for sum

```
b.promoledger.aggregate( [ 
    {$unwind: '$misscallDetails'},
    { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$misscallDetails.misscallCount" } }}
])
```